# Viewing a Flask app in the Cloud9 Test Browser

Tags: flask, cloud9-ide

I'm creating a web app based on Miguel Grinberg's Flasky app (from his book Flask Web Development).

When running `manage.py runserver` in the Cloud9 IDE, the command line tells me that it is running at http://127.0.0.1:5000/. However, when I type this IP address into the Cloud9 test browser, I see nothing. https://[workspace]-[username].c9users.io (with or without :5000) doesn't work either.

Here's my manage.py code:

```
from app import create_app
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Shell

app = create_app('default')
manager = Manager(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  manager.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MI8YIRDeGzU by Chris Lynch outlines the flask configuration settings  you need for the Cloud9 browser at around the 7 minute mark.  In order to start server hit the green run button near the top of the page to the right of the preview button.

```
#Insert the line below to to run on Cloud9    
app.run(host=os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'), port=int(os.getenv('PORT', 8080)))
#end insert, place above __name__ == __main__
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
    app.debug(True)
```

Comment: That's great. I've adapted those settings to work with the Manager:

`manager.add_command("runserver", Server(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080))`